# advice on storing 3rd party modules on my computer

Tags: python, module

How do you guys go about storing your python modules locally?  And how do you then go about referencing them in your python scripts?

Should I do this?

```
/home/python/modules
```

And then create a sub-directory for each module, like say the amazon s3 module:

```
/home/python/modules/amazon-s3/s3.py
```

Now I have to somehow tell python to look at these folders for modules, which I think is sys.path somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually store my modules in `/usr/local/lib/python` for the whole system, and `/home/user/lib/python` for the user.  That's if they weren't installed via the system package manager.  If they were a .deb or .rpm or whatever, they'll probably be placed in `/usr/lib/python`, as per the FHS standard, which specifies where different types of files should go on a POSIXish operating system.

Set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to have local packages be found by the interpreter.

Comment: @JGord: how to set environment variables depends on the shell you're using, but something like this will generally work: `PYTHONPATH=/home/user/lib/python python foo.py`

Comment: @Borealid ok so you put all .py files in the same directory, you don't create sub-directories?

Comment: @Blankman: No, when you run the package's `setup.py` it will usually create subdirectories for you.  Most packages come with a `foo.py` and a `foo/` directory; `foo.py` just includes the appropriate stuff from the subdirectory.

Comment: what if the person didn't build a package, they just have a .py file.

Comment: @Blankman: If you just have one .py file, why would it need a subdirectory?

Comment: it wouldn't your right, just want to know my options in organizing things.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I do this?

No.

Install them in `site-packages`, just like it says in the documentation.

http://docs.python.org/install/

http://docs.python.org/library/site.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're particularly concerned about managing python modules you'll probably want to look at  [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv), which lets you setup separate virtual python environments so you can separate out what modules are installed and used.